# What's wrong with this question [a workflow for philosophy]?

Tags: discussion

This is the question: [Can philosophy be described with a workflow?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/can-philosophy-be-described-with-a-workflow)

It is a yes/no question, and iff the answer is yes then there is a logically subsequent question.

Thank you.

Comment: Two downvotes so far, what's wrong with *this* meta-question?

Comment: Heh. Well voting is slightly different on meta. A quick response to all this might be that it's a bit too broad/open-ended to be entirely suitable for SE, which strongly favors questions that can be meaningfully answered in a few paragraphs

Comment: @JosephWeissman I'd be happy with answers that were simply a link or other type of reference. I'm asking for authoritative sources if such a thing can exist, otherwise a explained "no" would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's entirely clear what exactly you're asking here. Maybe you could share a little bit more about the context and motivations of your question? It can sometimes also help to share a little bit about what hypotheses you may have formed, what your research has turned up and so on. It would be helpful also perhaps to try to specify exactly what you might be looking for someone here to explain to you (in a few paragraphs.) In other words: what precisely is the problem you're encountering in your study of philosophy? Clearly articulating exactly what you're looking for help with will greatly improve the likelihood of getting a great answer.

Comment: I'll try, although I'm afraid my background in philosophy may not be good enough for that. I understand a general knowledge about philosophy leads to general questions, maybe general questions could lead to general answers. I wrote [a comment about this](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7780/can-science-be-described-with-a-workflow#comment-20150) some time ago.